# How to create links index in a xsl code for a book

Tags: html, css, xslt, xslt-2.0, xsl-fo

i'm using Altova XMLspy and  I'm setting up a new code to transform html documents in PDF. I've made a .xsl file to do it , but I can't link more documents in a single one. I'd like to make a book with an index and chapters with link bookmarks. How can I do it in the xsl file? what can I write ?

Comment: Do you have one HTML file or many to make one book?  If there are many, is there one HTML document that refers to all of the others?

Comment: many HTML files..

Comment: So how do you find which HTML files to process?  How do you know what order they should be in?

Comment: they are in a folder- I choose the order they should be in

Comment: Is there an XML or HTML file that includes the references to the files in the correct sequence?  Ideally, you'd have something like that that you can process to generate the XSL-FO in the correct sequence.

Comment: yes there is an XML file that include links/references . but i don't know how can i use it.

Comment: Edit your question to add an XML file that references two other files as a code sample so that we can see what the file looks like, and then we'll see what can be done with it.